# Trouble Scaling a Site for Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile

this is my first post here. 
I have a site which can be found at [www.justg.co.uk/stephSite](http://www.justg.co.uk/stephSite)  which just will not scale for mobile.  For some unknown reason the container div which has a fixed width and a margin of 0px auto is aligning to the left and not the center of the page.  Can anyone help me with this please.

Thanks in advance

G

Comment: Use `max-width: 100%` in `container`, insert the nav inside the container and use relative `font-sizes`.

Comment: hi Pigueiras thanks for that - has made a bit of a change although the <div>s holding the main page content are still off to the left (not done the font sizes yet)

Answer (score 0):

you dont have a fixed width on your nav/header, try fixing that

also look into media quires to detect width of display

looks like your using a css grid, why the fixed width, you should apply a grid class to it as well

Comment: hi thanks for that - i went fixed width as I had no intenetion of making this responsive.  I have applied the fixed with to the header but still not having it for some reason.  Do you think media queries are the way to go next?

Comment: with media queries you'll be able to detect screen size, and do specific css for that. I just looked at your site on mobile, and now understand what your talking about. it seems there is some sort of script that is resizing/reflowing your content, on window resize event.